# How to pass class object from swift to view controller which was a objective c file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have scenario in my project, where i need to pass a model class object to view controller file which is in objective c .

Let say employee.swift is my class it has name,address,phonenmber.

I need to pass this to objective c class as an argument to method in it.

How do we pass this as an arguemt? how do create object of swift class in objective c?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) might help you.

Sorry, didn't written as a comment since not sufficient reputation.